# Passing secret variable from YAML pipeline to Powershell script

Tags: powershell, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline where I run the AzurePowerShell@5 task.
The pipeline runs a separate powershell script like this:

```
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: "PowerShell Script"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "Platform - Management"
      ScriptType: "filePath"
      ScriptPath: ./post_migration/post-migration.ps1
      ScriptArguments: "-SubscriptionId ${env:SUBSCRIPTIONID} -ResourceGroup ${env:RESOURCEGROUP} -VmName ${env:VMNAME} -Username ${env:USERNAME} -Password ${env:PWD}"
      azurePowerShellVersion: "LatestVersion"
    env:
      PWD: $(Password)
```

The variable Password is marked as "Keep this value secret".
The reason to do like this is that we need to be able to set different values on the variables every time.

The param block for the variable $Password in the powershell script looks like this:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[SecureString]$Password
```

When I run the pipeline i get this error message:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert the "***" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".

All other variables seem to work fine, but not the secret.
Any suggestion about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The secret is passed as cleartext in the environment, not as a `SecureString`. There is no way to pass the secret from the agent to the script in encrypted/protected form.

You can probably cheat a little:

```
-Password $(ConvertTo-SecureString $env:PWD -AsPlainText -Force)
```

That will take the insecure value from the environment, then convert it before passing it into your script.

> ⚠️ Just understand, this isn't in any way more secure, since the value won't be encrypted and it will be passed plaintext in memory. But it will allow you to call a script that expects a secure string.

The agent's "keep secure" checkbox on variables does a few things, but not what you're expecting:

1. Variables marked as secure aren't automatically available to scripts - Unlike other variables which are set as an environment variable by default, secure variables need to be explicitly passed in through the `env:` section or inlined in an input using the `$(...)` or `${{ ... }}` or $[ ... ]` syntax:

   ```
   - pwsh: |
       echo $(SECRET)
   - pwsh: | 
       echo ${{ variables.SECRET }}
   - pwsh: | 
       echo $[ variables.SECRET ]
   - pwsh: |
       echo $env:SECRET
     env:
       SECRET: $(SECRET)
   - task: PowerShell@2:
     inputs:
       scriptArguments: $(SECRET) ${{ variables.SECRET }} $[ variables.SECRET ] $env:SECRET
     env:
       SECRET: $(SECRET)
   ```
2. Variables marked as secure are scrubbed from the logs - The primary purpose of marking a string as secure is to tell the agent to not accidentally expose the value through the logs. So every time a secret is written to Standard Out/Error the value is replaced by `***`, the same is done in the deug logs that are written to the agent's disk.
3. Secrets can't be passed to another job through output variables. - The agent will try to detect when a secret is passed to an output variable and block this. This prevents the secret from being logged in the initialization phase of the next job, since output variables don't carry the `secret-true` flag unfortunately.

What secrets do not do:

1. Secrets aren't stored in protected memory - Since the value must be passable to any executable, script or task, it can't be stored as a `SecureString` at all times. When you explicitly pass a secret to a step, it's passed in as plain text. This is due to the fact that there is no equivalent of `SecureString` that will work everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. I tried your tips `The parameter value "" is not a valid encrypted string` but I get this error: `The parameter value "" is not a valid encrypted string`

Comment: Oops, I saw now that I pasted the wrong code in the first place in my comment, but I think you got what I meant :)
Both these give the same error message:
`-Password $(ConvertTo-SecureString $env:PWD)` and `-Password $(ConvertTo-SecureString "$(PWD)")` gives `The parameter value "" is not a valid encrypted string`

Comment: Not sure I get what your suggesting @iRon, can you show an example?

Comment: Ahh of course, you need to add `-AsPlainText -Force`. Answer updated.

Comment: (got confused, `+1` after all ). with regards to your warning, "*⚠️ Just understand, this isn't in any way more secure*", as I see it; there is a small security improvement in this question/answer towards pushing the `ConvertTo-SecureString` outside the scope of the script by using  `[SecureString]` parameter instead of an often inappropriate used string parameter (`[String]$Password`)  as anybody that executes this (`post-migration.ps1`) script manually is forced to provide a `SecureString`.

Comment: The `-AsPlainText -Force` doesn't make any difference here.
Still getting the `not a valid encrypted string` error

Comment: The error in the question is referring to the parameter. I am not able to simulate the specific `The parameter value "" is not a valid encrypted string` on the `[SecureString]$Password` parameter. Are you sure this error isn't from somewhere else in your script? I guess you trying to do an `Invoke-Command` and supplying the `$Password` for `-Credential` which is not the same type (`[SecureString] ≠ [PSCredential]`).

Comment: In my edit I placed the extra switches outside the `$( .. )` instead of inside. Edited the sample above.

Comment: @iRon yeah, from the perspective of the script, it's probably more safe. But by shoehorning a plaintext environment variable into a secure string doesn't make it suddenly secure or encrypted. A memorydump would immediately show the plaintext value. There is no way to be more secure in the agent by default.